# UWP VirtualKeyboard shows NumericPin layout in simple textbox

Tags: c#, uwp, user-input, virtual-keyboard

I have multiple textbox controls in different views in my app. For each textbox inputScope is set to default or AlphaNumeric. In some scenarious when i open a ContentDialog and close it , KeyboardLayout becomes NumericPic layout for all textboxes, even if i click on windows taskbar keyboard button.
NumericPic  is not set anywhere, already checked in all code. Does someone knows anything about this ? Or maybe is a windows issue ?
Checked on Lenovo Tablet , Windows 10 Home Single Language v 1607 and Chuwi Tablet.

[Scrren](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mpqp.jpg)

Comment: If you do not open the `ContentDialog`, does has any problem?

Comment: Yes , i already figured the issue. In content dialog i have a hidden usercontrol with a PasswordBox confirmation with input scope as pinCode.
Seems is a UWP bug that on closing keyboard cannot change InpuScope anymore on other input control focus (