# How to use only NumericPin keyboard into all application? UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, virtual-keyboard

I developing an app in UWP, architecture 64x. With C#, W10 in kiosk mode.

I need to show and use only numeric keyboard for all input's into all application, but the keyboard provided by windows when i use *InputScope="NumericPin"* in TextBox element the NumericPin keyboard is showed, but when control  lose focus for a moment the standard keyboard appears and disappears.

I already tried this, but it works just like what I have explained:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280229.aspx

I also  considered use an external keyboard app service  and it works perfectly, but my boss say it is the last resource.
http://chessware.ch/virtual-keyboard/index.php

What i looking for is something like:

- use the NumericPin keyboard as static in display every time.
- the only keyboard layout available be NumericPin keyboard.

I finded this related question but says the same what me:
[UWP VirtualKeyboard shows NumericPin layout in simple textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107587/uwp-virtualkeyboard-shows-numericpin-layout-in-simple-textbox)

Thanks for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to show and use only numeric keyboard for all input's into all application, but the keyboard provided by windows when i use InputScope="NumericPin" in TextBox element the NumericPin keyboard is showed, but when control lose focus for a moment the standard keyboard appears and disappears.

As you said, the keyboard provided by windows and the type of keyboard is determined by `InputScope` property of input control. You could manually set `InputScope` property. However, you could not set keyboard for the input control that has not been determined `InputScope` property.

For your requirement, I think you could set global `style` for input control in `Application.Resources`. such as `TextBox`,`RichEditBox` etc.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="InputScope" Value="NumericPin"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: really your solution has the same effect with <TextBox InputScope="NumericPin"/>, and setter is for when the element haven't the propertie as default.